# How does Keras callback execute in distributed training using tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

As we know, while writing model using keras, we can define [callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks) to do something like learning rate schedule, early stop and so on. Using early stop as an example, I'm wondering while execute the training in a distributed environment, which node execute the callback? Or all the nodes execute the early stop using the metrics data locally calculated? Or there is a chief node execute this?

Answer (score 0):

when you are using the MirroredStrategy, the training is managed by the CPU, so it will be the CPU which calls the callbacks i think.